# How to change what default(T) returns in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, default, nullable

I would like to change how default(T) behaves for certain classes. So instead of returning null for my reference types I would like to return a null object.

Kind of like

```
kids.Clear();
var kid = kids.Where(k => k.Age < 10).SingleOrDefault(); 

if (kid is NullKid)
{
  Console.Out.WriteLine("Jippeie");
}
```

Anyone know if this is at all possible?

Answer (score 13):

> Anyone know if this is at all
>   possible?

It is simply not possible at all.

But maybe you want to use [DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419.aspx) instead:

```
kids.Clear(); 
var kid = kids.Where(k => k.Age < 10).DefaultIfEmpty(NullKid).Single(); 

if (kid == NullKid)
{  
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Jippeie");
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can't change default(T) - it's always null for reference types and zero for value types.

Comment: This answer is not altogether correct in its particulars, since the default value of a bool is not zero but false (to name just one value type whose default value is not zero; see [this article for a list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values). The canonical reference is [Default value expressions in the C# language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#default-value-expressions).

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
var kid = kids.Where(k => k.Age < 10).SingleOrDefault() ?? new Kid();
```

Comment: Shorter equivalent: `var kid = kids.SingleOrDefault(k => k.Age < 10) ?? new Kid();`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think, it is possible. What you could do however, is to create your own extension method `SingleOrCustomDefault` or something like that.

Comment: That's definitely the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 2):

I think you've already got the answer in your question: if/switch statement. Something like this:

```
if (T is Dog) return new Dog(); 
   //instead of return default(T) which is null when Dog is a class
```

You can make your own extension method like this:

```
public static T SingleOrSpecified<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,bool> predicate, T specified)
{
    //check parameters
    var result = source.Where(predicate);
    if (result.Count() == 0) return specified;
    return result.Single();   //will throw exception if more than 1 item
}
```

Usage:

```
var p = allProducts.SingleOrSpeficied(p => p.Name = "foo", new Product());
```

Comment: I think, the question remains: how can someone do this from inside of ...SingleOrDefault() !?