# Why compiler throw error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable?

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I put the code below, and also uploaded to a online c# compiler:
[jdoodle.com/a/1jww](http://jdoodle.com/a/1jww)
the code can compile and run online, however, it doesn't compile in my local visual studio.

I am using:

> Visual Studio 2017 15.9.13,
>
> Console app, .Net Framework 4.7.2
>
> Language version c# 7.3
>
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 2.10.0.0 (b9fb1610)

Below is the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string,int> myDict = new Dictionary<string,int>();
        myDict.Add("hello", 1);

        if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == true)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Hello" + value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

expecting to see Hello1 in Console.Output
Because if the condition is true, the Null-Conditional check must have returned a non-null value, and the key is existing in the dictionary and the value must have been assigned when returning from the TryGetValue method.

Because according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier):

> the called method is required to assign a value before the method returns.

---

update:
This is an open issue in https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32572
I think it's an true issue/bug if the requirement for compiler includes not to give false alarm. 
My arguments: 
Whenever CPU executing to the point inside the if bracket code block, the value must have returned from TryGetValue call and is NOT "unassigned local variable". An easier solution is to give something like "unable to determine assignment status" as warning instead of error, if compiler can't look forward for assignment status when interpreting null conditional operator.

Comment: FWIW: it works correctly without the `?.` - i.e. `if (myDict != null && myDict.TryGetValue("hello", out var value))`; in the general case, I can see how custom equality operators or truth operators could make this very hard to generalize...

Comment: I think you have found an edge case in the different compilers.

Comment: I knew it worked well without the ?. my current workaround is I do the null check before this. But I want to use Null-Conditional to demonstrate this issue as the compiler inferred wrongly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's due to the compiler difference.

In this fiddle, https://dotnetfiddle.net/5GgGNS, you can see the error, which is omitted in the mono compiler.

I think the error is valid due to the fact that this line

```
if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == true)
```

is not guaranteed to initialize the local variable `value`.

If you would rewrite it to:

```
if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == null)
```

it would try to access `value`.

Now, the `null` value, or `true` in your case, could be a function's return value, which would only be known at run time.

But, since all variables are basically [always initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8931226/are-c-sharp-uninitialized-variables-dangerous/8933935#8933935), it's just a compiler feature.

On the other hand, according to the C#5 specs:

> A local variable introduced by a local-variable-declaration is not automatically initialized and thus has no default value. For the purpose of definite assignment checking, a local variable introduced by a local-variable-declaration is considered initially unassigned. A local-variable-declaration may include a local-variable-initializer, in which case the variable is considered definitely assigned only after the initializing expression (§5.3.3.4).

But your code is C# 6.

So my conclusion is that the compilers interpret it differently. The Microsoft compiler takes the `?.` operator into account. You should file it as a bug, or finding at least, maybe even at both parties.

---

#### Argumentation

Fun fact, if you use this code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Dictionary<string,int> myDict = null;

        if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == null)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("Hello" + value.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

[using https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online , mono 5.10.1]

You'll see the actual initialization to `default(T)` at work. The output is `Hello0`. Nevertheless, it's remarkable because due to the `?`, and the fact that `myDict` is `null`, `TryGetValue` shouldn't be called and leaving `value` *"uninitialized"*.

> The null-conditional operators are short-circuiting. That is, if one operation in a chain of conditional member or element access operations returns null, the rest of the chain doesn't execute.
>
> [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

**But...**, since there are no uninitialized variables; if it compiles, the compiler will make sure it's behavior is not undefined.

---

So, since `value` *is* initialized, on run-time, the question remains if it's a valid compiler error at build time. Regarding to the run-time intend of the code it is (and that's why the error was there in the first place), but I think it remains a grey area.

Do note that according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793418/how-to-override-defaultt-in-c) `default(T)` is not override-able, which would actually lead to no condition where it fails.

---

By running this little test:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        //Your code goes here
        Dictionary<string,int> myDict = null;

        if (myDict?.Bar(out var test) == null)
        {               
            Console.WriteLine("does hit");
        }
    }
}

static class Foo
{
    public static object Bar(this Dictionary<string,int> input, out int test)
    {
        test = 3;
        Console.WriteLine("does not hit");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

[using https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-c-sharp-online , mono 5.10.1]

The output becomes:

```
does hit
```

And you can verify the correct run-time behavior of the `?.` operator.

Comment: according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8  
value
TValue
When this method returns, contains the value associated with the specified key, if the key is found; otherwise, the default value for the type of the value parameter. This parameter is passed uninitialized.
@Stefan:  0 is the default value of int type, so why you think it's not correct?

Comment: You're right. That's actually a good case showing the Mono compiler is wrong handling null-conditional operator. Maybe CSC is concerned of the same case, so they decide to leave the "value" variable unassigned whenever it's in a null-conditional operator. I can't find documentation, that's my guess.

Comment: It also crossed my mind that it's an different interpretation of the [var out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.0/out-var) usage. If it `defaults` somewhere upfront, that that's actually what the issue is.

Comment: @yww325: I have to rephrase; it's not an error... at least I think....but it is an edge case. I'll rephrase my answer

Answer (score 3):

The null conditional `?.` removes the guarantee that `value` will be assigned to since `TryGetValue` will only be called conditionally if `myDict` is not `null`.

You enforce the assignment of `value` inside the `if` statement afterwards with `== true` since the left side will return `null` if `TryGetValue` is not called due to `myDict` itself being null.  The compiler, however, cannot make this inference leap in the general case so you have to help it out either by testing `myDict` for `null` beforehand (and skipping `?.`) **or** initializing `value` beforehand.

Comment: yes, I think you have the point, it's a "inference leap" for a static language, the interpretation of null conditional operator is not smart enough to consider the IF condition is comparing with a constant value of true. Although it's constant, compiler still think it's dynamic and not using it in IL generation.

__________________________________________________________________________
By the way, IF statement and conditional operator ?: behave the same when with null conditional operator ?.  in CSC compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest initializing the value variable before your "TryGetValue" call.

Comment: while that would work around the compiler, that a: doesn't explain anything, and b: is an ugly solution IMO

Answer (score 0):

The null-conditional operator introduces a different execution path where it short-circuits `TryGetValue`. However, the `value` variable exists anyways since it is scoped outside of the `if` and `TryGetValue` statements, which would indicate this flavor of syntactic sugar must result in the good old declaration of the variable prior to its use. For instance:

```
if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello" + value.ToString());
}        
//Current issue aside, this is legal as the variable exists at a higher scope, 
//beyond the if and TryGetValue statements although the brackets give the illusion of scope.
value = 2;
```

Should be equivalent to:

```
int value;
if (myDict?.TryGetValue("hello", out value) == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello" + value.ToString());
}           
value = 2;
```

Which also results in the compilation error.

However, the same error would be issued for `myDict` if it was `null` and you didn't use the null-conditional operator:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myDict; //Not initialized        
//You would get the warning for myDict here instead
if (myDict.TryGetValue("hello", out var value) == true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello" + value.ToString());
}
```

In other words, `myDict` *can never be* `null` and compile without the same error so there is no need to use a null-conditional operator. This is why removing it fixes the issue.

That being said, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#out-variables) states:

> No need to assign an initial value. By declaring the out variable
>   where it's used in a method call, you can't accidentally use it before
>   it is assigned.

So, in theory you are accidentally using the variable before it's assigned because the language constructs allow it. However, the compiler is identifying an issue at a lower level and not letting you go through with it.

In my mind, it's valid compiler verification obscured by syntactic sugar fog.

Comment: The `Dictionary<string, int> myDict; //Not initialized` variant would actually result in a compile time error.

Comment: @Stefan: That is the whole conversation. A compile time exception.