# TryGetValue on a null dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, trygetvalue

I am trying to use `TryGetValue` on a Dictionary as usual, like this code below:

```
Response.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL].UserDefined.TryGetValue("action", out var actionObj)
```

My problem is **the dictionary itself might be null**. I could simply use a "?." before UserDefined but then I receive the error:

```
"cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'"
```

What is the best way I can handle this situation? Do I have to check if `UserDefined` is null before using TryGetValue? Because if I had to use `Response.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL].UserDefined` twice my code could look a little messy:

```
if (watsonResponse.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL].UserDefined != null && 
    watsonResponse.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL].UserDefined.TryGetValue("action", out var actionObj))
{
    var actionName = (string)actionObj;
}
```

Comment: Use a variable for that lengthy term.

Comment: Check for null before you make a call. This way you do not have to use TryGetvalue.

Comment: @SmithaKalluz: Those are entirely unrelated concerns.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a null check (`??` operator) after the `bool?` expression:

```
var dictionary = watsonResponse.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL].UserDefined;
if (dictionary?.TryGetValue("action", out var actionObj)??false)
{
    var actionName = (string)actionObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That actually solved my problem. But I still receive a ```Use of unassigned local variable 'actionObj'```... is my only option here to declare that object before the ```if``` statement?

Comment: @AlexandrePaiva Yes you would have to do so. If you think about the logic you will see why that error is thrown

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, I'll declare the object before then. Just for feature reference, I found a question with a interesting discussion regarding the use of local variables inside the TryGetValue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779825/why-compiler-throw-error-cs0165-use-of-unassigned-local-variable

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to compare to `true`.

It looks slightly weird, but it works with three-valued logic and says: is this value `true` but *not* `false` or `null`

```cs
if (watsonResponse.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL]
    .UserDefined?.TryGetValue("action", out var actionObj) == true)
{
    var actionName = (string)actionObj;
}
```

You can do the opposite logic with `!= true`: is this value *not* `true`, so either `false` or `null`

```cs
if (watsonResponse.Context.Skills[MAIN_SKILL]
    .UserDefined?.TryGetValue("action", out var actionObj) != true)
{
    var actionName = (string)actionObj;
}
```