# Setting the default(class) value

Tags: c#

It's possible I set a `default()` value for `MyClass`? My idea is that, instead if return `null` when I call `default(MyClass)`, it returns a instance of this class, but with default values.

**For instance:**

```
class MyClass {
     // Default value.
     static public readonly MyClass Default = new MyClass();
}
```

So when I call:     `var defaultValue = default(MyClass);`
It to be similar to: `var defaultValue = MyClass.Default;`

I need to use it with generics:

```
class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue>: Dictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    public TValue GetOrNull(TKey paramKey) {
        return ContainsKey(paramKey) ? this[paramKey] : default(TValue);
    }
}
```

So if I use `GetOrNull()` with an inexistent key, it'll not return `null`, but the default instance of `TValue` (`MyClass.Default`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change what default(T) returns in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088682/how-to-change-what-defaultt-returns-in-c)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793418/how-to-override-defaultt-in-c?lq=1

Comment: Instead of a `GetOrNull` method why not make a `GetOrDefault(Tkey paramKey, TValue defaultValue)`.

Comment: You can, but hopefully this is well documented if others use your class. Most users will expect the default of any class to be `null`, and an instance with default values to be one created with the default constructor. You are making your class behave similar to a struct (for example: `new Guid() == default (Guid)`), which may be confusing. I would be afraid some folks would call `.FirstOrDefault` on a list of your class, and then compare the result to `null` rather than `default(class)`.

Comment: You can however create a static method `Empty()` that returns a *default* instance of the class. Your difficulty is that you are trying to name it with a keyword `default`. It is possible that `@default` might work.

Comment: @EvAlex that's just absolutely wrong. What makes you think it's only for value types?

Comment: @jcl I'm sorry, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

That's not the aim of the `default` keyword, and I'm glad you can't redefine it: you'd make things really complicated.

The `default` keyword is there so that when using value types (which can't be null) you get a default object state (for reference types, null, and for value types, the parameterless constructor state). That is a well-defined behaviour and if you changed it you could cause much grief.

Value-types have an implicit public parameterless constructor if you didn't define one (so `default(T)` can actually return a value), where all its fields are initialized to their `default()` values (check it if you want: define a `struct` with a constructor that takes parameters and no parameterless constructor, and try `new myStruct()`: it compiles and works).  That's not the case for reference types... if a class doesn't have an explicit public parameterless constructor (or no constructor defined at all), there's no way you can instantiate it without arguments.

Think about it for a moment, in case you changed the `default()` implementation, what could this code do (take the default implementation syntax as pseudocode)?

```
public abstract class Foo
{
   protected Foo(int x)
   {
   }      
   protected override Foo default()
   {
     return new Foo(50); // You can't instantiate an abstract class
   }
}
//..
Foo myFoo = default(Foo);
```

How is `default(Foo)` suppossed to instantiate a `Foo` at all, if it's abstract?
But to make it even more complicated... imagine you have this value type, which -needs- to be able to instantiate with `default()`:

```
public struct Bar
{
   public Foo myFoo;
}
//
var myBar = default(Bar); // this just can't return null since
                          // Bar is a value type
```

What could possibly (other than `null`) be the value of `myOtherFoo.myFoo` if `Foo` is abstract?

But let's make it easier and take `abstract` out of the question (let's pretend it wouldn't let you change `default()` in abstract classes and would give a compiler error), and think about this case:

```
public class Foo
{
   public Bar myBar;      
   protected override Foo default()
   {
     return new Foo();
   }
}
public struct Bar
{
   public Foo myFoo;      
}
var myBar = default(Bar);
```

You have just created and endless initialization loop.

This could be of course both statically and runtime analyzed and both compile-time errors (like those where you define a struct field inside the same struct type definition) and runtime exceptions could be thrown... but you are just taking away the well-documented behaviour of `default()`.

#### Possible workaround

If you want to emulate the behaviour of `default(T)` in structs on classes, then just replace `default(T)` for `new T()` and add a `T: new()` constraint. This would require those classes to have a parameterless constructor and not be abstract, but you can think of it as your "`default(T)`" implementation if you wish (without those two constraints, there'd be no way any `default()` method involving creating an instance would work either).

In your example, this would be:

```
class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue>: Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
  where TValue : new()
  {
    public TValue GetOrDefault(TKey paramKey) {
      return ContainsKey(paramKey) ? this[paramKey] : new TValue();
  }
}
```

This would, however, disallow returning `null`. As a possible workaround, you could "tag" the classes where you'd like NOT to return null with an empty interface and instead of using the `new()` constraint, use `Activator.CreateInstance()` when the type implements that interface, or return null otherwise... something like:

```
interface IWithExplicitParameterLessConstructor {}

class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue>: Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TValue GetOrDefault(TKey paramKey) {
        return ContainsKey(paramKey) ? this[paramKey] : 
            (typeof(IWithExplicitParameterLessConstructor).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(TValue)) ? Activator.CreateInstance<TValue>() : default(TValue));
    }
}
```

Then for classes "tagged" with that interface, it'll create a default instance (using a parameterless constructor: it'll throw an exception is none is defined), and would return `null` for all others (and the corresponding default value for value types).

Otherwise, if you **NEED** to be able to have a `default` instance value without a public parameterless constructor (this smells from afar), you could document a convention in your code, and use reflection to find a static property value or static method in the class type. As stated, this smells from afar, and I definitely not recommend it, but it is doable:

```
public static class GetDefaultHelper
{
    public static T GetDefaultInstance<T>()
    {
      var propInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty("Default", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
      return (propInfo != null) ?  (T)propInfo.GetValue(null) : default(T);     
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
Foo foo = GetDefaultHelper.GetDefaultInstance<Foo>();
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/JO8YfV

Answer (score 0):

Add a new parameter of type **TValue** for *default* value.

```
public class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TValue GetValueOrDefault(TKey paramKey, TValue @default)
    {
        TValue value;
        if (TryGetValue(paramKey, out value))
            return value;

        return @default;
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
public class DictionaryEx<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public TValue GetValueOrDefault(TKey paramKey, Func<TValue> funcDefault)
    {
        TValue value;
        if (TryGetValue(paramKey, out value))
            return value;

        return funcDefault();
    }

    public TValue GetValueOrDefault(TKey paramKey)
    {
        return GetValueOrDefault(paramKey, Activator.CreateInstance<TValue>);
    }
}
```